# What do you call a person who wants a package to be delivered to him?

Tags: single-word-requests

So in shipment systems the word would be "recipient", but that word is from the point of view of the shipping company, what would it be called from the point of view of the person ordering the package?

To give more context, I have a system where a user can either be a courier or "someone who requests stuff from abroad", and these two sides of the system get matched up. I want one word to describe the words in quotes. What do I call you when you sign up to be "someone who requests stuff from abroad"?

Edit: Secondary Question, What if the person who requested the package and the one who will receive the package aren't the same person? How do I differentiate between them?

Comment: It's still the *recipient* of the package - whatever one's point of view. Until the package is actually delivered it's the *intended recipient*.

Comment: What if the recipient isn't the same person who ordered the shipment? How do I differentiate between them?

Comment: What you are saying, in effect, is that your question as posed was not clear.

Comment: The requester requests shipment of the parcel; the shipper ships the parcel; the recipient receives the parcel. You should show what research you've already done, and explain what confuses you.

Comment: @Davo: I think requester -> shipper/courier -> recipient makes the most sense. I didn't research the subject because I didn't know how (other than looking up various words in the dictionary). My issue is mainly trying to find the most suitable words that would make all users of my app understand it intuitively, it's a UX issue basically.

Comment: @Davo: if you like, you can post this as an answer, I'll upvote it, and I'll mark it as the correct answer if I don't find a _better_ answer in a few days.

Comment: What relationship exists between the person who requests stuff from abroad and the recipient?

Comment: I don't think this question warrants an answer, as these terms are all pretty easily looked up. Just remember that the shipper(sender) might not be the courier.

Comment: Research for a question like this might typically involve having a discussion with someone who works in the relevant industry and asking them what terms they use. "Research" doesn't have to mean "web research".

Comment: How are ***client*** or ***customer*** not suitable?  I'm envisioning a service where some customer wants to buy something from a foreign country and someone else says, "I'm going there, I'll bring it back for you." Now if you insert a middleman- someone who interfaces with the customer to get their money and deals with the courier then maybe that middleman is an importer.

Comment: @Jim because we're a double-sided market, both requester and courier/shipper are my customers. And the recipient is usually a friend of the requester who would then give the package to him, but I need to differentiate between them in the app (the requester enters the receiver contact info).

Comment: @all: I apologize for not being clear enough with my question despite my best efforts. I didn't want to go on and explain all the small details of our business as I felt it would be too much unnecessary info, but now I realize that this is what I should have done.

Comment: @Mark: The reason I couldn't research by looking at the shipping industry is because our business is different from how the industry works, and we don't want our users to get confused and think we actually ship the stuff ourselves. And our very few direct competitors have confusing apps that the users don't understand well, and we wanted to make our app more clear and easier to use, this includes better wording (for UI and Marketing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for "someone who places an order", I think [**"orderer"**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/orderer) fits the bill.

The person who receives the package can be referred to as **"the receiver"** or **"the addressee"**.

Comment: well it's not necessarily an order to "buy", it's an order to have any kind of package/parcel be delivered to you.

"Consumer" also doesn't fit because both sides of the system are consumers of the service (which essentially matches the "orderer" with the courier).

Comment: @HassanSelim  I've edited.